# How to display images from plist in cocoa mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am developing mac desktop app using objective c. i have array of images to display one after one when button pressed, so i am want to use plist to store image names and i want to display image on image view using plist.

Answer (score 0):

Just load your plist where you stored you image's paths to an array like this :

```
NSString *myfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                  pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"plist"];
imagesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];
```

and then when you want to display an image, juste get it's path from the array above, example :

```
UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: [imagesArray objectAtIndex:4]];
myImageView.image = img;
```